# SonarQube Server shows zero issues for C-Sharp Code

Tags: c#, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Our Sonar Build Environment details as follows:

```
- SonarQube Server Version - 5.6.6 (64-Bit). 
- Sonar Client Build Operating System – Ubuntu - 14.04.5 LTS (64-Bit). 
- Sonar-scanner- Version - 3.0.3.778.
- sonar-csharp-plugin Version -5.11.0.1761.
```

When I tried to run the sonar-scanner though Jenkins, scanning finished successfully, However post that it shows zero issues over sonar server dashboard. Could you help me to resolve the same.

Comment: Please post the log of the Sonar scanner.

Comment: And please format the logs properly when you post them.

Comment: My complete log has more than 20000 characters, it is not allowing me to post the same here.

Answer (score 0):

Per [SonarC# documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1441900), analysis of C# projects must be done with the [SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) on a **Windows environment** (where you would anyhow develop your .Net applications). Analysing .Net projects on Linux is bound to fail, and in fact there might soon be a fail-fast mechanism preventing that.

Comment: Analysing the .Net project on Linux new/updated plugin will going to release?

Comment: Why don't sonar just scan the file?